# 3 блока iframe на весь экран без полосы прокрутки

Tags: html, iframe

Пытаюсь сделать три блока, выводимые через `iframe`:

Один крупный слева, занимающий 80% экрана, два других справа, друг над другом, занимающие 20% по ширине, и по 50% по высоте.

Если делать такими ровными цифрами, появляется полоса прокрутки справа, хотя все должно вмещаться на экран.

```
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   .layout DIV { 
        float: left;
    }
   .col1 { width: 80%; height: 100vh;}
   .col2 { width: 20%; height: 50vh;} 
   .col3 { width: 20%; height: 50vh;}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body bgcolor="#000000">
  <div class="layout">
   <div class="col1"><iframe id="1" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="блок1"></iframe></div>
   <div class="col2"><iframe id="2" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="блок2"></iframe></div>
   <div class="col3"><iframe id="3" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="блок3"></iframe></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Пробовал добавлять `overflow: hidden` - не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в css

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно объяснить путь решения, указать на конкретные ошибки, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п.